# P/Invoke with optional out pointer

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

How can I call a method like [StartXpsPrintJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which optionally returns a pointer to a COM object, depending upon whether NULL is passed for the OUT parameter.

Example in C++ would be a call with `printTicketStream` set `NULL`:

> ```
> IXpsPrintJob *job = NULL;
> IXpsPrintJobStream *jobStream = NULL;
> hr = StartXpsPrintJob(
>             printerName,
>             NULL,
>             NULL,
>             NULL,
>             completionEvent,
>             NULL,
>             0,
>             &job,
>             &jobStream,
>             /* _Out_  IXpsPrintJobStream **printTicketStream */ NULL);
> ```

I know I could make the optional parameter `IntPtr` rather than `out IntPtr` and just pass `IntPtr.Zero`, but that would require four P/Invoke signatures of this function to encompass all of the options, not to mention what the calling code would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the parameter is really a pointer to a pointer which will hold the result, allocate a pointer and pass it as `IntPtr`.

Example signature:

```
[DllImport("XpsPrint.dll", EntryPoint = "StartXpsPrintJob", PreserveSig = false)]
private static extern void StartXpsPrintJob(
    // other parameters omitted for brevity
    IntPtr printTicketStream);
```

Example use:

```
IXpsPrintJobStream ticketStream = null;
bool getTicketStream = false;

IntPtr ppTicketStream = IntPtr.Zero;
if (getTicketStream)
{
    ppTicketStream = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(IntPtr.Zero, ppTicketStream, false);
}

StartXpsPrintJob(ppTicketStream);

if (getTicketStream)
{
    IntPtr pTicketStream = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ppTicketStream, typeof(IntPtr));
    ticketStream = (IXpsPrintJobStream)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(pTicketStream, typeof(IXpsPrintJobStream));
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppTicketStream);
}

//ticket stream now has the result from StartXpsPrintJob or null, if it was not requested
```